# copy elements in foreach if there are no more than 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I use a regular slick slider on the page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider-images').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        arrows: false
    });
});
```

```css
.slider-images {width:100%;margin:0px auto;}
.slider-images .slider-image {position:relative;}
.slider-images .slick-slide {margin:10px;}
.slider-images .slick-slide img {width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="slider-images">
        <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CUmIpxR.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/g7aX7wR.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cPToo7F.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qVbD6iK.png">
        </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

I use php to display images in this slider

```
<div class="slider-images">
    <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
        <div class="slider-image">
            <img src="<?= $image->url?>">
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The following question follows, in my slider settings there are 3 pictures for slides, that is, for it to work, I need to upload 4 pictures

But I may have such a situation that I will upload 1 or 2 pictures

How can I make it so that when I upload 1 image on the PHP side, then 3 more images will be created during the output. The same thing if I upload 2 pictures, it should copy 2 more

Accordingly, if I myself upload 4 pictures or more, then nothing needs to be done

It turns out that I need to count the number of elements, and if there are less than 4 to copy in the for loop

If there is only one image, then it seems not so difficult, but what if I have 2 images, let's say? I then need to make 2 copies of the first image, and it's not all clear how to do it

```
<div class="slider-images">
    <?php if (count($images) < 4) { ?>
        
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <div class="slider-image">
                <img src="<?= $image->url?>">
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And is it possible to do cloning in javascript itself?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider-images ').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        arrows: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you need placeholders for images if the count < 4?

Comment: If you generate it via php, just calculate the count objects in `$images` collection. Then simply subtract the amount of images that you have from 3. 3 -  `amount_images_in_collection`, if it will be less then three but not equal to zero make some else statement with for loop that will generate amount of objects that are basically your empty slides. In case of subtraction result will be negative value don’t do anything. Enjoy ;) And don’t forget to make number three as some sort of constant in the code which you can reuse.

Comment: @SergeyLigus I realized that I need to count the number of elements and if there are less than 4 then copy them in the for loop. But if I have 2 elements, I need to make 2 copies of the first element and so that there are 4 in general. This moment is not entirely clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate images with [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function and then [slice array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) in case there are more than 4 images.

```php
<div class="slider-images">
    <?php if (count($images) < 4) { ?>
        <?php
        $images = array_merge($images, $images);
        $images = array_merge($images, $images);
        $images = array_slice($images, 0, 4);

        foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <div class="slider-image">
                <img src="<?= $image->url ?>" alt="<?= $image->name ?>">
            </div>
        <?php }
        ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <div class="slider-image">
                <img src="<?= $image->url ?>" alt="<?= $image->name ?>">
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```